# How to set a default function in Laravel 5.1 just like "before_filter" in CakePHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to restrict users to access some pages without getting login.

I am using `if(Auth::check()):` for this, but I don't know where to place this correctly, as in CakePHP we put this kind of code in `before_filter` function,
But how to use this in Laravel 5.1.

Which function behaves as the default function in Laravel 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel there is the same concept with before filters please check the following link http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters

Comment: If you need help in implementing the filters just ask :)

Comment: Laravel 5.1 doesn't use the concept of Filters anymore. You should implement it as [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware)